# System.Web.Helpers is not found on the server, what's wrong?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I developed an ASP.NET MVC 3 web application and it's working correctly locally, but not on the server:

```
Line 18:<add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

How do I fix the fact that the server can't find this assembly?

Comment: You need to give us the error message as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's looking for a GAC'd assembly reference to that assembly. Do you have that assembly installed on the server? If not, you need to set it to `bin deploy`.

Here's how you do that:

#### To set the Copy Local property to True

1. In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project node for the project.
2. In the Project Designer, select the References tab.
3. Select a referenced component in the References list.
4. The properties associated with that reference appear in a list in the Properties window.
5. Select Copy Local from the left-hand column, and then click the arrow in the right-hand column to change the value to True.  ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))

To set up your project to `bin deploy`, [follow these instructions laid out by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx).

Comment: FYI - 'Copy Local' does not work with GAC assemblies http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Chris It wasn't clear in my post, but the user needs to change the type of reference to bin deploy: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. right click on project in solution exploret.
2. select Add diployable dependencies
3. checked Asp.net MVC and click ok

Comment: This works in visual studio 10, but the option was removed from later versions. see here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1845993.aspx?Add+Deployable+Assemblies+in+VS2012+